# tikz:drawing flowcharts

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi thanks for your answer, but I still get the same problem I want it outside the box on the east.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning, fit}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70,text width=2cm, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{io2} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70,text width=1cm, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{process2} =  [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{elip}=       [ellipse, minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=3cm,fill=yellow!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (start) [startstop] {Début};
\node (in1) [io2, below of=start] {Entrer  T };
\node (in2) [process, below of=in1] {Calcul vecteur $k(T)$ };
\node (in3) [io, below of=in2] {Entrer équation différentielles };

\node(in4)[io, below of=in3]{Condition initial n0,t0,tf};
\node(in5)[process, below of=in4]{$t=t0$ };
\node(in6)[decision, below of=in5]{$t \leq{tf}$ };
\node(in7)[process, below of=in6]{Résolution };

\node(in8)[process, below of=in7]{$t=t+dt$ };
\node(in9)[io, below of=in8] {afficher n(t) et p(t) };
\node(out)[startstop,below of=in9]{Fin};
\coordinate (a) at ($(in5)!0.4!(in6)$);
\coordinate (b) at ($(in8)!0.5!(in9)$);

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (in2);
\draw [arrow] (in2) -- (in3);
\draw [arrow] (in3) -- (in4);
\draw [arrow] (in4) --(in5);
\draw[arrow] (in5) -- (in6);
\draw[arrow] (in6) -- node[left]{oui} (in7);
\draw[arrow] (in7) -- (in8);
\draw[arrow] (in9) -- (out);

\draw [arrow] (in8) -- ++(0,-0.75) -- ++(-3,0) |- node[pos=-0.1]{} node[above]{} (a);
\draw [arrow] (in6) -- node[below]{no} node[above]{} ++(3,0) |- (b) -- node[left=1.5cm, yshift=-3pt]{} (in9);

\node(box)[draw, ultra thick, dashed, fit={($(in5.north)+(-4cm,0.25cm)$)($(b)+(4cm,0)$)}, ] {};
\node at (box.east){ ODE15s}; % place the label
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the ODE15s `node` an `anchor=west`?

Comment: yes the same problem it stuck on the dash

Comment: `\node[right] at (box.east){ ODE15s}` would give you what you expect. And not related, but I'd rather write "Entrer équation*s* différentielles" (le pluriel à équations).

Comment: thank you so much